# Which one is better to minimize SSE or MSE in ADMM?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am minimizing the following ERM objective function.
\begin{equation}
\sum_i^m \ell(w;x_i,y_i) + r(w)
\end{equation}
within ADMM framework. ADMM convergence takes a long time (primal and dual residual decay very slowly) when I divide the loss term by $m$. Although, the objective function starts going up after certain number of iterations and change is quite small.
 Can somebody tell me if minimizing SEE is better/worse than MSE in ADMM or ERM in general?